# Find inside of rectangle using outside points

Tags: java, csv, logic, java.util.scanner

I have a csv file with numbers(i.e. 0, 2, 34, 0, 2,...) all on one line.  I am using a scanner to read them from a file.  The file represents an in-game map which is quite large.  I know the width and height of this map.  While scanning this file, I only want to capture the brown rectangle(part of the game's map) in the image below.  I am scanning the file and wanting to put the values from the csv file into a short[].

```
int mapWidth        = 8;
int mapHeight       = 6;
int rectangleWidth  = 5;
int rectangleHeight = 3;
short[] tmpMap = new short[rectangleWidth * rectangleHeight];

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
scanner.useDelimiter(", ");
```

I also am lucky enough to know the 4 corners of the rectangle that I need.  The dark brown squares(four corners of the rectangle I need to capture) can be represented as:

```
int topLeftIndex     = 17;
int topRightIndex    = 21;
int bottomLeftIndex  = 33;
int bottomRightIndex = 37;
```

[image: visual representation]

I know that during my scan method I can check to see if I am within bounds of the rectangle and the blue highlighted boxes with the following:

```
if (count >= topLeftIndex && count <= bottomRightIndex){
//within or outside (east and west) of rectangle
```

I am having trouble thinking of the logic for identifying and not storing the blue highlighted squares.

The size of this rectangle, size of the overall map, and dark brown point are just numeric examples and will change, but I will always know them.  Can anyone help me out?

Here is what I have so far:

```
private static short[] scanMapFile(String path, int topLeftIndex, 
    int topRightIndex, int bottomLeftIndex, int bottomRightIndex)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
    scanner.useDelimiter(", ");

    short[] tmpMap = new short[mapWidth * mapHeight];
    int count = 0;
    int arrayIndex = 0;

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        if (count >= topLeftIndex && count <= bottomRightIndex){ 
        //within or outside (east and west) of rectangle
            if (count == bottomRightIndex){ //last entry
                tmpMap[arrayIndex] = Short.parseShort(scanner.next());
                break;
            } else { //not last entry
                tmpMap[arrayIndex] = Short.parseShort(scanner.next());
                arrayIndex++;
            }
        } else {
            scanner.next(); //have to advance scanner
        }
        count++;
    }
    scanner.close();
    return tmpMap;
}
```

*NOTE: **this is not school work** :)  Any help would be tremendously appreciated.*

Comment: So you want to identify when you are really only in the brown rectangle and NOT in the lightblue area?

Comment: correct, you got it.  Sorry if it was confusing.  Hard to explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to it like this:

```
public boolean isInside(int n) {
    if(n >= topLeftIndex && n <= bottomRightIndex) {
        if(n % mapWidth >= topLeftIndex % mapWidth
          && mapWidth % mapWidth <= bottomRightIndex % mapWidth) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This first checks, what you have already checked and then checks, whether the "column" is right as well.
This works always if you know the top-left index, the bottom-right index, and the map width.

Comment: but if the location of the rectangle moves it will break, no?  aka if the brown box shifts over to the right 1 spot

Comment: @KisnardOnline oh, you mean you need it to be depending dynamically on the numbers of the corners of the rectangle? Let me edit...

Comment: @KisnardOnline Does it fit your needs now?

Comment: Coding it into my game now... should the 8 be n?

Comment: if(n % mapWidth >= topLeftChunkIndex % mapWidth && n % mapWidth <= bottomRightChunkIndex % mapWidth) { is what it should read... you gave me what I needed to get this going.  Thank you!!

Comment: Actually this does not work when the map grows larger the the size of the rectangle.

Comment: @KisnardOnline What exactly do you mean? It should work for your example, and in your example the map is larger than the size of the rectangle.

Comment: Yes it does work for that example, but it was my fault for not putting it true to life.  The chunk in my real situation is much smaller than the map... chunk is 225,145 and map(right now) is 2200,2200.

Comment: I am rechecking it as correct as I see it was my fault for not specifying a properly scaled example.  I will also 'answer' with what I did to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to capture all of the sides:

```
int topLeftChunkIndex = characterX - (chunkWidth / 2) + ((characterY - (chunkHeight / 2)) * mapWidth);
int topRightChunkIndex = topLeftChunkIndex + chunkWidth - 1;
//int bottomRightChunkIndex = characterX + (chunkWidth / 2) + ((characterY + (chunkHeight / 2)) * mapWidth);
//int bottomLeftChunkIndex = bottomRightChunkIndex - chunkWidth + 1;

int[] leftChunkSides = new int[chunkHeight];
int[] rightChunkSides = new int[chunkHeight];

for (int i = 0; i < chunkHeight; i++){
    leftChunkSides[i] = topLeftChunkIndex + (mapWidth * i);
    rightChunkSides[i] = topRightChunkIndex + (mapWidth * i);
}
```

And here is how I checked later:

```
public static boolean isInsideMapChunk(int n, int[] leftChunkSides, int[] rightChunkSides) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chunkHeight; i++){
        if (n >= leftChunkSides[i] && n <= rightChunkSides[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```